# pyproject.toml didn't run properly (reason Deprecation) Error when running "! pip install auto-sklearn" on Kaggle Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kaggle, pyproject.toml, auto-sklearn

it says "Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully, DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API"
I saw this issue discussed on Git for example but no solution like updating or downgrading pip or python worked for me.

I tried to run:

```
import os
os.system('sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev')
os.system('pip install qt5')
os.system('! wandb login be213aaff4ff14945d480abc18697d8664bba8c8')
#os.system('')
os.system('! apt-get remove swig')
os.system('! apt-get install swig3.0 build-essential -y')
os.system('! ln -s /usr/bin/swig3.0 /usr/bin/swig')
os.system('! apt-get install build-essential')
os.system('! pip install --upgrade setuptools')
os.system('sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev')
os.system('! pip install auto-sklearn')
```

before which were all given as solutions but none worked.
I also tried going back to pip==23.1.1 where people said the issue didn't come up.

for the qt5 I got

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qt5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for qt5
```

which I can't fix because everyone online I saying to "just update pip" which didn't resolve it either

for swig I got

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/swig': File exists
```

the error is pages long but also includes numpy which I also tried to update but that didn't work either

the full error is pages long but the beginning seems to give the most information:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1618 lines of output]
      <string>:17: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
      <string>:116: DeprecationWarning:
      
        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
        For more details, see:
          https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
      
      
      INFO: C compiler: gcc -pthread -B /opt/conda/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/conda/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/conda/include -fPIC
      
      INFO: compile options: '-c'
      INFO: gcc: test_program.c
      INFO: gcc -pthread -B /opt/conda/compiler_compat objects/test_program.o -o test_program
      INFO: C compiler: gcc -pthread -B /opt/conda/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/conda/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/conda/include -fPIC
```

and in the end it says

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```